# Pushing multiple tasks on the same thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Hi I am trying to do something like this:

I have multiple threads on one side (say A) and a single thread on one side (say B ). Threads on side A are doing some things and routinely need to submit some task to thread B. How to do this in Java?

I can create multiple threads in A easily, what I have found is that I can schedule tasks at side B but each of them will be run by a separate thread. I want them all to be run by a single thread so that they can be run in the order they are submitted.

Comment: Looks like a classical Producer-Consumer problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem can be solved with two instances of [ExecutorSevice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

You don't need to create `Thread` at all. Just have a [fixed thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) at one side (A), and submit tasks to a [single threaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) one at the other side (B).

Simple example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final ExecutorService parallel = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    final ExecutorService single = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    final List<Callable<Void>> parallelTasks = IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(i -> (Callable<Void>) () -> {
                LockSupport.parkNanos(Duration.ofMillis(100).toNanos());
                System.out.printf("%s parallel %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), i);
                single.submit(() -> {
                    System.out.printf("%s synchronous %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), i);
                });
                return null;
            }).collect(toList());

    parallel.invokeAll(parallelTasks);
    parallel.shutdown();
    parallel.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    single.shutdown();
    single.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Output:

```
pool-1-thread-1 parallel 0  
pool-1-thread-4 parallel 3  
pool-1-thread-3 parallel 2  
pool-1-thread-2 parallel 1  
pool-1-thread-9 parallel 8  
pool-1-thread-6 parallel 5  
pool-1-thread-8 parallel 7  
pool-1-thread-7 parallel 6  
pool-1-thread-5 parallel 4
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 3
pool-1-thread-10 parallel 9  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 1  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 8  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 2  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 5  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 7  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 0  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 6  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 4  
pool-2-thread-1 synchronous 9
```